# How i can use multiple like query in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to use multiple queries in my codes with single row. But it doesn't work with multiple. It works only with one query.

**Here is my code:**

```
$kuafor = $this->input->post("kuafor");
$donem = $this->input->post("donem");
$ilk_tarih = $this->input->post("ilk_tarih");
$son_tarih = $this->input->post("son_tarih");

$ara = $this->db->select("*")         
       ->or_like(array("kuafor_id"=> $kuafor, "tarih"=> $donem))
       ->or_like(array("tarih >="=> $ilk_tarih, "tarih <="=> $son_tarih))
       ->get("hesaplar");

foreach($ara->result_array() as $row){        
    if(!empty($row["tarih"])){
        echo "var";
    } else {
        echo "yog";
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

Here is my SQL code:

```
CREATE TABLE `hesaplar` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `kuafor_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `tarih` varchar(50) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Tablo döküm verisi `hesaplar`
--

INSERT INTO `hesaplar` (`id`, `kuafor_id`, `tarih`) VALUES
(12, 3, '2018-02-03', 13, 3, '2018-02-04' );
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: it does not work.

Comment: What do you want to query? What's the purpose of your query? Could you explain it in SQL or in words?

Comment: i want search start date and end date. also i want search date with the same query. all will be in the one query.

Comment: let me show you my sql codes.

Comment: `LIKE` is inappropriately used when making a comparison like `>`, `=`, or `<`.  `LIKE` is only appropriate when you are using wildcard characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to separate each `like` statement :

```
$ara = $this->db->select("*")         
      ->or_like("kuafor_id", $kuafor)
      ->or_like("tarih", $donem)
      ->or_like("tarih >=", $ilk_tarih)
      ->or_like("tarih <=", $son_tarih)
      ->get("hesaplar");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `or_where` instead of `or_like`:

```
->or_where(array("tarih >="=> $ilk_tarih, "tarih <="=> $son_tarih))
```